# How do i create low lying smoke (similar to Zootopia), in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, smoke-simulation, collision

Hello Blender community,

I am a huge fan of the Disney movie Zootopia, the amount of physics and detail really drew me into 3D animation and design. Although I always had an interest in 3D technologies, designs, animation, etc. This movie really pushed me into getting into making 3D stuff, and learning Blender.

Anyway, as a learning experience, I decided to take multiple different 'animating techniques' of the movie and try to replicate in Blender.

The scene I'm trying to replicate? The Limo scene, specifically the low, lying smoke.

[image: Limo Scene, with low-lying smoke]

I have analyzed this scene many times and I have concluded on some of its properties

1. It lively collides, with the characters, meaning that it is not a textured material, it is most likely mesh based.
2. It has a lower temperature value than other objects, which is why when the characters breathe, an amount of fog appears (This is because the movie was designed in the Hyperion Renderer, I don't really need this, but if you know how to make this please let me know)
3. It is somewhat fluffy, although not cloud-like. When a mass of this smoke comes together, it makes a fluffy looking mass.
4. It is affected by gushes of air, when Judy (the bunny) lands on the ground, a gush of air extrudes the smoke around her. Sudden movements have this effect as well.

Now I'm pretty sure that making this is in Blender is difficult or even impossible, considering that Disney has their own proprietary rendering engine named Hyperion and they can drop smoke in within a couple of clicks. And they have HUGE render-farms that can render these details.

But I just wanted to know if it is possible. As I may be getting an internship for Disney Animation, I need to know this stuff

***UPDATE:***
So, I see that using a still frame from the movie to demand something that needs multiple frames, is pretty stupid

So feel free to study this clip:
https://www.yahoo.com/movies/zootopia-clip-fur-skunk-170000173.html
(and if you haven't seen the movie, do yourself a favor and please have a watch)

Also, I would like to know, how to smoke kind of 'flows', the way that it lies low to the ground moving. Not just stuck in place similar to how Cycles does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>I've tried really simple smoke in Blender and here is what I've got:</del>

<del>[Gif with sample](http://recordit.co/Drr9CtfCok)</del>

<del>You just need to play with smoke temperature and domain height.</del>
<del>Sphere is nothing more but smoke collision.</del>

<del>UPDATE:</del>

<del>Here it is how to make it:</del>

<del>[Gif steps](http://recordit.co/Upd8sb8DOz)</del>

<del>If you need more info just specify what you want.</del>

<del>Sorry that I didn't cover timeline for sphere animation.</del>

### UPDATE 2

### Smoke.

1. Create a simple plane. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh > Plane*
2. With still selected plane go to *Physics* tab then select *Smoke* and set smoke type to *Flow*. Next change the *Temp. Diff.* to *-0.01*. It will keep smoke near the ground and even after collision smoke will very slowly descend.

[image: Step 2]

3. Create cube <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Mesh > Cube* and position it as you can see in picture below. It must be a little wider then our plane. So scale it a little <kbd>S</kbd>. This cube will be our smoke domain.

[image: Step 3]

4. Having selected cube go to *Physics* tab, select *Smoke* then smoke type *Domain*.

   - First thing you want to change is *Resolution*, I've set it to 64. Higher values gives more detailes to our smoke.
   - Secondly you need to check *Smoke Adaptive Domain*, this will only calculate domain where smoke actually is.
   - Next check *Smoke High Resolution*. This will add more details to smoke. Set *Resolution* to *2* and *Noise Method* *Strenght* to *1*. Lowering *Strenght* gives us smooth smoke.

[image: Step 4]

5. Now save your file and go to *Smoke Cache* in *Domain* options. Choose *File Format > OpenVDB* (this is optional).
6. Now you can *Bake* or just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to start animation. Second option will be slow trough te first loop.

As you can see nothing happend which in this case is good :) Now let's make some...

### Noise.

We will create collision object and little bit of turbulance to give this smoke a life.

1. Create *Turbulance* - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Force field > Turbulance* and set *Strenght* to about 0.5. This option is totally up to you. you can even skip it. What it does is it create some air movements in our domain and based on location (room, outdoor etc.) you will want to adjust position of it and strenght.
2. Create *UV Sphere* - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh > UV Sphere*. In *Tools* tab select *Shading* as *Smooth*. Position sphere in a corner of our domain and right above plane. Check on your timeline if you are on frame 0.

[image: Step 2_n]

3. In *Top ortho* view (sphere selected) hit <kbd>I</kbd> and choose *Location*. Now you can go to frame 50, move your sphere and again hit <kbd>I</kbd> and choose *Location*, and repeat this step. You can also select *Automatic keyframe insertion* (red dot under the timeline) and do this little faster. See gif below.

[image: Step 3_n]

4. With selected sphere go to *Physics* tab then select *Smoke* and set smoke type to *Collision* and *Collision type > Animated*.

That's it! You can now bake it and play it. Should look like this:

[image: Final]

There is still many to do. Smoke texture, lighting, correct density and so on.
If you want I could try to make it but I'm not really good at it.

Here is the blend file:

[image]

### UPDATE 3

[image: Flow]

Here I've changed *Turbulance* to *Wind*. You can adjust wind speed and noise.
If you want to make it fluffy try higher resolutions. I don't have render farm and 64 is max usable/testing for me.

[image]

Comment: "Play with the settings" isn't really an answer.  Please add some more details as to what exactly you did.

Comment: I've just lowered smoke temperature to something little above 0 (~0.1-0.2) and changed domain height in edit mode. That's all. If you need something really specific, show me the scene (not screen) and I think I could follow you trough all steps. I don't know how skilled you are in Blender so it's hard to elaborate.

Comment: (FYI I'm not the OP.)  Please try to add some more details to your answer (with the edit button).  Things like screenshots and details of what settings to use and how they affect the result, as well as how you set the domain and objects up would improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: @PGmath ok, I'll do this when OP tell me what he need. I'm new here as well ;)

Comment: @LukeD , you might take a look at my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60776/rigging-multiple-meshes/60792#60792 . BlenderSE offers the possibility to add images to imgur, so there is no need to use links to other sites. Small steps and a little more text is also more helpful than just a video without sound. You also might want to add licecap or a similar screencast tool to your tool setup.

Comment: @metaphor_set Thanks for advice! I'll use those in my answers. I'm new here ;)

Comment: Yeah, me too, more or less ;-) Three months are quite short.

Comment: 3 days here :P Even when I post right answer the way I post it make it minus. But that's ok, I think ;)

Comment: @LukeD Please write the steps to the answer so that it stands on its own. Video and screen captures should be used to support and clarify, but don't make the answer a video only. Also if you are relying on external links you run the risk of the answer becoming useless if the links disappear or expire...

Comment: @LukeD please read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/1056#1056

Comment: @cegaton thank you I couldn't find how to add .gif here. I'll update my answere tomorrow with proper assets. I hope that my method still is usefull even besides the way of presenting it.

Comment: Hello, everyone in this flame war

I have updated the question, in the hopes that it will help get a better answer.

Sorry, for starting a war down here.....

Comment: It's not a war, they want to maintain quality of BlenderSE and I'm noob here...

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand, how to make the smoke, can someone please explain EVERY step. and also the keyboard shortcuts (i need work there)

Comment: I'll make a proper tutorial tomorrow for you. With every step and shortcut :)

Comment: I think this update is better explained ;)

Comment: That does help, but i think you need to see my re-purpose to see

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5iD7B6s82uJZ2oxSkdHNGtBam8/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to have the glowing water, come in from the background and the low lying smoke come in from the sides......But I want the smoke to be like the one in Zootopia. The fluffy, naturally moving kind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43882/discussion-between-luked-and-naturalistubuntu).

Comment: This is ridiculously nice. Quick question... Do you think you could use a smoke sim very similar to this to render ink bleeding out via capillary action onto a paper using dynamic paint? Very impressive. Would love to see a render.

Comment: @troy_s please provide some sample (video will be the best) and I can try it. Probably the best way will be to make new question. Just mention me there in comments.