# How would I go about transferring weight paints to a different part of the same mesh?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have a character who wears armor, and the armor is combined to be the same mesh as the character. I believe due to the thickness of the armor, automatic weights didn't work as well on it as it did for the character itself. In my research I read a lot about the data transfer modifier, which looks like exactly what I would want, except my armor and character are the same mesh. I could separate the meshes but it feels unnecessary as the armor will never be removed.

Is there any way to project my existing weight paints on my character to the armor he's wearing?

Comment: Are they the same mesh or the same object? In the first case, weight paint should work anyway, in the second case it shouldn't be a problem to separate and recombine them after weight painting again. In any case, they don't have to be the same object **or** mesh. Good planing and parenting is also key, as described in my answher [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60792/23985)

Comment: I realized separating the mesh, using the data transfer, and recombining did no harm. Thanks for your help!