# How to achieve vapor or steam effect with smoke sim?

Tags: rendering, physics

How can I achieve this effect of a plume of vapor with the smoke sim or other tool?

[image: Vapor]

Comment: Do you have any video of this effect? Is the smoke rises fast or slow? Or do you need this only for still render?

Comment: For a still render.

Comment: Check first my other answers here about smoke, there is almost everything explained for your case and if you can't deal with it, write a comment and I will try to replicate exact effect. 1. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61531/jet-stream-of-water/61551#61551 2. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60769/how-do-i-create-low-lying-smoke-similar-to-zootopia-in-blender/60772#60772

Comment: I would much appreciate it if you could replicate the effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Result:

[image: Final]

### Basic setup:

1. Change *Blender units* to *Metric*.

[image: Metric]

2. Create Circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh* > *Circle*) with 2cm *Radius* and *Fill Type* > *Ngon*.
3. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type in *"Quick Smoke"*. Select it.
4. Position domain as in the picture:

[image: setup]

5. Change *Light Paths* > *Volume* to 2. It will allow light go trough smoke thus it could be white.

[image: Volume]

### Smoke Domain:

1. Change *Resolution* to 64. Higher resolution = more details.
2. *Behavior* > *Temp* to 0.4. Smoke will rise higher.
3. *Behavior* > *Vorticity* to 4. Smoke will have more 'wrinkles'.
4. Check *Smoke Adaptive Domain*.
5. Check *Smoke High Resolution* and change *Noise Method* > *Strenght* to 1.

[image: Domain]

### Material:

Use this node setup:

[image: Nodes]

You can control smoke density by changing *Multiply* value.

### Final thoughts and .blend file:

You can play with *Resolution* and/or *Smoke High Resolution Divisions* to get more detailed smoke.

You should save your file and change *Smoke Cache* to *OpenVDB* > *Float (half)* it will speed up whole setup.

To play animation hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or first *Bake* it under *Smoke Cache*.

Note that I'm using HDRI for lighting, it is packed in .blend file.

[image]