# How to make a whiff of steam rising off a mug of coffee?

Tags: workflow, smoke-simulation

I want to make steam rising off a mug of coffee.
I attempted to create wisps of steam or visible heat vapors (not sure what the phenomenon is called) rising from the coffee by using Quick Smoke.  That was way too much - tried changing parameters but my efforts did not reduce the blast of smoke to a "snaky looking" wisp.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19474/how-can-you-color-smoke-based-on-the-smokes-temperature For the "heat shimmer" effect just create a fully transparent glass object with a very slight refraction and very slight roughness

Comment: I've made several answers regarding steam/smoke here, this is most relevant for your question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60769/how-do-i-create-low-lying-smoke-similar-to-zootopia-in-blender/60772#60772 But check out these too to get more info about smoke: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63782/how-to-achieve-vapor-or-steam-effect-with-smoke-sim/63837#63837 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61531/jet-stream-of-water/61551#61551. You have there all kinds of smoke from non-moving to jet stream. Take a close look at smoke material.

Comment: Has this one been mentioned yet? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42731/creating-wisp-materials-in-cycles/64978#64978 wisp material

Answer (score 1):

I did it by using an Emission shader for the volume.  I mixed with the given quick smoke setup that uses Volume Scatter and Volume Absorption, but the mix is so low for them I suspect that I could leave them out.  I also animated the density from 1 to 0. (Stuff is grayed out in the domain's settings because I baked it.)  I changed things like the Vorticity and Dissolve time, and Noise Method and Strength. My problem was getting the steam to be white instead of gray. Maybe if I got rid of the Volume Absorption I wouldn't need the Emission?  It doesn't look quite right since the steam is lighting up the inside of the cup.

[animation (it's still rendering and needs about 30 more frames for the full 70 frames.)](https://streamable.com/2f8cj)

[image: nodes]

[image: domain]

[image: flow]

Comment: Here's the node setup without the Volume Absorption and a single frame, so I think the node setup could definitely be tweaked and improved.  http://i.imgur.com/g0Pr3g1.jpg  http://i.imgur.com/nKItXiA.png  The Multiply for the Volume Scatter Density was dialed down as was the Mix shader for the Emission.

Answer (score 0):

You should either fake it with a plane with roughness, or use closer to real life settings in a smoke simulation. You can then play with the material to fine tune it. You'll probably want some turbulence (a force field) to make the smoke trail more natural.

Comment: Could you please extend your answer? Add some examples, images, etc.?