# High pressure steam/gas/vapor leak simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm trying to achieve result like on this reference
https://youtu.be/MQiPAhScDGA

I already checked these posts

- [Jet stream of water](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61531/jet-stream-of-water)
- [How to achieve vapor or steam effect with smoke sim?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63782/how-to-achieve-vapor-or-steam-effect-with-smoke-sim)

It seems that due to their age, the .blend files from them don't give you what you expect.

I also watched a lot video tutorials on Youtube, but there is nothing similar to what I'm looking for so I could use the exact settings.

I also tried to play with the settings myself, but I came across the fact that even if you adjust something more or less acceptable with lower resolution division settings, but at higher resolution the result can be significantly different.  Moreover, even if you bake the cache, the result in viewport will still be different than after the rendering.

Because of the following problem it takes a very long time to render smoke  even in EEVEE, so it turns out that I can not play with the settings, because to see the final result, I first need to spend about 30 minutes to bake the cache and another 30 minutes to render it. I don't understand what to do.