# How to make clouds in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, scene, volumetrics

I have a sci-fi scene with a floating platform and a camera that pans around the platform. I want to add clouds underneath. Since I am going to pan around the platform, I can't use an image texture for the clouds, However modeling a bunch of volumetrics clouds takes too long and after skimming a bunch of tutorials I couldn't find a material that worked right with my scene. any suggestions?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60769/how-do-i-create-low-lying-smoke-similar-to-zootopia-in-blender

Comment: possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44941/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-volumetric-clouds-for-cycles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To model the clouds faster, use the add-on CloudGen that comes packaged with blender. It does the material for you and there are good preset options. If it is taking too long to render, render two shots: Your standard shot with the platform and then another one that is the clouds on a transparent background. Then, you can use the compositor to layer the two shots and if your camera is the same, it should look seamless.