# Smoke trail Effect - emitting from animated object and fadding over time

Tags: animation, modifiers, particles, physics, keyframes

I would like to add a smoke trail emitting horizontally from the exhaust pipe of my moving object.

I want the smoke to **fade out** over time/distance and to **follow the motion path** of my object.
What would be the simplest way to accomplish this effect in Blender 2.8 ?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112746/atmospheric-trail (possible duplicate) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139754/making-a-realistic-dust-trail

Comment: Is there another way to do smoke trails without having to use scripts or addons?

Comment: DRF's answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/112753/15543 uses no scripts / addons.

Comment: I will give this a go, but I was after a more realistic effect, like jet trails from a 747 (if they still exist).

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18296/how-to-make-a-heat-distortion-effect  Pretty much play around with emitters (some mesh object)  and settings like  lifetimes of particles etc to get smoke you are after.  Then animate it as would any other object to create the trail.

Comment: Still not exactly what I want to do. Its more like the jet stream trails you see from jet engines when they are flying through dry cool air on a clear winter day.

Comment: Yet another https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45328/trail-particles-ending-in-a-point